# Weird value of a pointer in C/C++ allocated from a sys-call

Tags: c++

Can anyone explain why this code prints out 'A' and not its memory address?

```
#include <iostream>`
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

using namespace std;

#define PAGESZ 0x1000

int main() {
    char *p = (char*) mmap(NULL, PAGESZ, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                           MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    *p = 'A';
    cout << p << endl;
}
```

Comment: Would you expect `char *str = "abc"; cout << str;` to print the address of the str pointer or the string `abc`?

Comment: Oh.. I see... Its treating it like a c style string... That's what I get for mixing C and C++ like that. Thanks!

Comment: To print the address do `cout << (void *)p`.     That uses a different overload of `operator<<()` which prints the address rather than treating the address as the first character of a c-style string.